# Can You Add A Column To Wordpress Table? Will Upgrade Remove It?

Tags: wordpress

Is this possible to add a column to wp_post? What will happen to it when it is upgraded? Is it possible to tell wordpress not to delete column if upgrade might remove it?

** Please do not post why I should use the other tables or make a new table. **

Answer (score 0):

I do not know off the top of my head whether it will get deleted when upgrading, but why would you want to do that? That's what the postmeta table is for.

Comment: Yes but there is a particular architecture that in the end would be better to require a column since a column is better than longtext fields or creating an extra table ( especially for WPMU w/ 3000 blogs ). 

Also, the db will be exported to sqlite dbs in another server, and trying to fetch a specific field export from many fields in post-meta isn't proper in the long term.